# Obtaining trial version of ArcGIS Publisher?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license, arcgis-publisher

I would like to save my MXD files as PMFs. I don't have a license of ArcGIS, only the 60-day trial.

Is there a similar trial for the Publisher?

I understand that's the only way to save PMF files (through the Publisher).

Comment: We found it cost effective to export to GeoPDF. (PDF is a much better supported standard).

Answer (score 1):

**60 Day Trial for ArcPublisher**

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/publisher/evaluate.html